# Problems with adding/removing a view within a view

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, view, ios6

I'm trying to get add/remove a view (_countdown) to a view below, no problems with adding the view. But when I'm trying to remove it, nothing happens. All of my NSLog() are getting called, so everything should work. But when it gets to -(void)removeAnimation (trying to remove the clockview with an animation, so it's not visible in the mainview anymore), nothing happens. Why? I can't really see why. I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of hours now but I just can't find any way of getting it to work...

```
@implementation MainViewController {
    ClockView *_clock;
    ClockView *_countdown;
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
timerAddClock = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkNotificationExist) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

checkNotificationExist:

```
 -(void)checkNotificationExist {
        NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        if ([userDef boolForKey:@"NotificationExist"]) {
            NSDate *notificationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"NotificationDate"];
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

            NSTimeInterval interval = [notificationDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];

            if (interval > 0) {
            if (_clock == nil) {
                _countdown = [[ClockView alloc] initWithCountdownToTime:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:interval]];

                [self.view addSubview:_countdown];

                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                                     animations:^{
                                    [_countdown setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - _countdown.frame.size.width) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height), _countdown.frame.size.width, _countdown.frame.size.height)];  
}];
                            }
                    self.timeIntervalTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(checkTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                }
}
```

checkTime

```
-(void)checkTime {
    NSLog(@"running");


    [timerAddClock invalidate];
    self.timerAddClock = nil;

    NSDate *notificationDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"NotificationDate"];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [notificationDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now];

    if (interval < 1) {
    NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDef setBool:NO forKey:@"NotificationExist"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"NotificationDate"];

    self.addAnimation = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(removeAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

removeAnimation

```
-(void)removeAnimation {
    NSLog(@"Removing animation...");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^{
                         [_countdown setFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - _countdown.frame.size.width) / 2, (self.view.frame.size.height - 800), _countdown.frame.size.width, _countdown.frame.size.height)];

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [_countdown removeFromSuperView];
                     }];
```

Comment: Add NSLog (@"%@", _countdown); after _countdown allocation, addsubview and before removefromsuperview and post the result.

Comment: If removeFromSuperView is definitely called, one thing comes to mind first: _countdown is not pointing to the view you think it is.  Is it possible that it is created multiple times such that the value is overwritten without the previous object being removed?  Or maybe it becomes nil somewhere along the way.  If you're using ARC, maybe it's prematurely disposing the reference.  Check the address of _countdown when initialized, then again when it's removed to verify it's the same.

Comment: After allocation: AppName[1413:c07] <ClockView: 0x9df7170; frame = (0 -7; 232 86); layer = <CALayer: 0x23973b40>>

Comment: Before removeFromSuperView: <ClockView: 0x9df7170; frame = (112 -320; 232 86); animations = { position=<CABasicAnimation: 0x9d5d600>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x23973b40>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should call `[super viewDidLoad];` in your `- (void)viewDidLoad;` method. Also, you may have added the `_countdown` view as a subview somewhere, which may be causing issues?

You may also want to check all your `NSTimer`'s again, and make sure that they are being called correctly. Your `addAnimation` timer seems suspicious to me.

You could try just hiding the view instead of removing it from the superview. That would work for sure.

Hope that Helps!

Comment: It worked. Feel so stupid now. Called the timer for adding the view at multiple places. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that you might be adding more of one of that _countdown views. So if checkNotifications is called several times (there is a timer with an interval, so I assume that is possible) and the line where to add the _countdown view is run more than once, then if you only remove on of the views you won't see anything because the repeated view would be on top.

Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment, it seems that there is an animation in progress when you call removeFromSuperview. So, the view isn' t removed.

I think that the problem is in your checkNotificationExists method: you create an animation, but start the timer outside the completion block. Try to move it inside the completion block